# Fetch from background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am writing an iPhone app, and I have a remote server that will deliver content. I would like to have my app poll the server once per day to see if there is new content, even if it's not running or in the background. I would also like to do this without setting up an APNS. Any advice?

Comment: I don't know definitely because I haven't actually tried but i'm about 90% sure that this *isn't* possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that, either when your 'not' running or if you are running in the background.  The best you could do is to download once per day when your app is first run / pushed to the foreground.

You could use remote notifications to "prompt" the user to bring the app to the foreground so that it could download something?

With the current apple IOS guidelines, that is about the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I read that you are trying to avoid using APNS, but I am wondering if you are trying to avoid it for the right reasons, especially when it is designed to efficiently solve the scenario you are describing.  I've seen many developers seek alternative solutions to APNS simply because the technology appeared to be complex to use after looking at Apple's documentation.  The online documentation does go into a lot of details, right down to the binary protocol level.

But just to be sure you know, there are open-source libraries whose only purpose is to shield you from all these technical details.  Some libraries are more complex than others, but some are remarkably user-friendly.  If you have not done so already, you might like to take a look at [JavaPNS](http://code.google.com/p/javapns/) and other similar projects.